# restart number for img class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I've lot of images and I want to add class for all images and for the first 7 images it should name as `"img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7"` and again after that this should be named as previous `"img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7"`

So I tried this but not working its naming `img1` for all images after first 7 images

```
$('#someid img').addClass(function(idx){
    if(idx > 6){
    idx = 0;
    }
    return "img" + (idx + 1)
});
```

Comment: where are you incrementing idx?

Comment: Where are you incrementing idx?

Comment: return "img" + (idx + 1)

Comment: @developerCK & Ozair: `idx` is the parameter to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `idx` is not a counter but the actual index of the element.

Use the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) instead:

```
$('#someid img').addClass(function(idx){
    return "img" + (idx % 7 + 1)
});
```